# Move selected content from one listbox to another

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been cracking my head around this one for a solid hour now:
I have created this form to select present members of a meeting on the left side, then move the absent ones to the right.

[image]

This is the code that is intended to work with the corresponding buttons:

```
Private Sub MoveSelectedItem(xQuelle As Object, xZiel As Object)
Dim y As Long
For y = xQuelle.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
 If xQuelle.Selected(y) Then
    xZiel.AddItem xQuelle.List(y, 0)
    xZiel.List(xZiel.ListCount - 1, 1) = xQuelle.List(y, 1)
    xQuelle.RemoveItem (y)
 End If
Next
End Sub
Private Sub MoveAllData(xQuelle As Object, xZiel As Object)
Dim y As Long
For y = xQuelle.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1

    xZiel.AddItem xQuelle.List(y, 0)
    xZiel.List(xZiel.ListCount - 1, 1) = xQuelle.List(y, 1)
    xQuelle.RemoveItem (y)

Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
MoveAllData Me.lstAbwesende, Me.lstAnwesende
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
MoveSelectedItem Me.lstAbwesende, Me.lstAnwesende
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
MoveAllData Me.lstAnwesende, Me.lstAbwesende
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
MoveSelectedItem Me.lstAnwesende, Me.lstAbwesende
End Sub
```

However, once I start to run it and press the first button to move my selected item from present to absent, I get a runtime error, that the property List could not be set. Type conflict. Pressing Debug it gets me to this line:
    `xZiel.List(xZiel.ListCount - 1, 1) = xQuelle.List(y, 1)`

The same error in the MoveAllData private-sub occurs if I press the button to move all entries from left to right.

What could be wrong with my code?

Comment: `y` has what value when you receive the error?

Comment: Depending on the entry I select, so if I pick the first one y= 0 and so one

Comment: Excel but similar concept: https://www.contextures.com/excelvbalistboxmoveuserform.html

Comment: How do you create the initial list for the left listbox? Is this a two- or a one-dimensional array? From the screenshot it looks more like a one-dimensional one then you don't need the line that throws an error.