# Output Text to Document based on InputField Value

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this InputBox ("numbers") in my VBA form where I want to enter a value (usually between 1 and 10).
Based on the number I entered I want it to add the word "TOP" and a value to my Word document where I placed a bookmark ("t_1"), e.g. when I enter "3" I want it to output

- TOP 1
- TOP 2
- TOP 3

This is what I am currently using but I am getting an error for my Range..

```
Private Sub 
Dim tops As Integer
 
      With ActiveDocument
        .Bookmarks("t_1").Select
      
            For Each tops In Range(Numbers)
             
             Selection.TypeText ("TOP" & tops)
          
          Next tops
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your Range? It is not a defined array. Range is a troublesome name to use for a variable in vba.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon It is supposed to be the value that I enter in my input box, but I don't think that that is being accomplished ...

Answer (score 0):

### This should work:

```
Private Sub ProduceHeadings()
' Charles Kenyon
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69723303/output-text-to-document-based-on-inputfield-value
    Dim iTops As Long, i As Long
    On Error GoTo NoBookmarks

    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("t_1").Select
    iTops = InputBox("Number of Headings? (Integer)?", "Number of Headings")
    For i = 1 To iTops
        Selection.TypeText ("TOP " & i)
        If i < iTops Then Selection.TypeText(vbCr)
    Next i
    On Error GoTo -1
    Exit Sub
NoBookmarks:
    On Error GoTo -1
    MsgBox "The bookmark t_1 cannot be found in " & ActiveDocument.Name & "!", Buttons:=vbCritical
End Sub
```

**Your bookmark should already have a bullet if you want these to be bullet points.**

Here is a [temporary link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pp17heakgc9pd8b/deleteme%20add%20bullets.docm?dl=0) to a sample document with the macro.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pp17heakgc9pd8b/deleteme%20add%20bullets.docm?dl=0

### Far simpler, IMO, would be to use AutoText with a SEQ Field.

Simply have a Sequence field named something link myHead.

```
{ SEQ myHead }
```

Create and save AutoText entries for each of the setups you want using the sequence field:

So your AutoText named _top1 would have:

- TOP { SEQ myHead }

Your AutoText named _top3 would have:

- TOP { SEQ myHead }
- TOP { SEQ myHead }
- TOP { SEQ myHead }

If you later wanted to add another in your document, you would use the _top1 to add another.

Here is [my writing on AutoText](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm). http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm

Here is [my writing on the Sequence Field](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields). http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields

Here is my article on [dealing with Fields on the Microsoft website](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501). https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501

Comment: Thanks, it does work, however it produces a new bug in my context: In this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69634384/move-selected-content-from-one-listbox-to-another?noredirect=1#comment123085418_69634384 I have a picture of how my form looks like - once I press the button to generate all the text, it does not close anymore with your version. I changed the iTops = InputBox ... to = numbers, the name of the inputbox where I enter the value originally (AnzahlTops in the form). Do you know how I can get it to close again?

Comment: You did not say you were in a UserForm! -- "it does not close anymore" -- What does not close?

Comment: @user17193804 - there is nothing in the code in the answer that prevents your user form from closing.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I really like your second approach with the Sequences - However implementing it in my code did not work. Is it possible to print the AutoText that I named "Top" in the document? 
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("t_1").Select
    iTops = AnzahlTops
    For z = 1 To iTops
        ' Selection.TypeText ("TOP " & z & vbCr)
        ' Selection.ActiveDocument.BuildingBlockEntries(Top).Insert Where:=NonclientRange, RichText:=True
        ' NormalTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries(Top).Insert Where:=NonclientRange, RichText:=True
    Next z
    On Error GoTo -1
    Exit Sub